# Displaying a silverlight plugin in a jQuery UI dialog box not sizing correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a login page which detects if silverlight is installed and will degrade to html when it is not.

I'm using jQueryUI.dialog to display both; the dialog box appears but is too small to see the content completely and i have to resize it manually.

I think it's something to do with the order the javascript is running on the page. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. What I did was change from using an OBJECT tag to creating the Silverlight control using Javascript.

Example:

```
$('#silverlightControlHost').dialog({
    title: 'My app',
    width: 800,
    height: 600
});
Silverlight.createObjectEx({
    source: 'ClientBin/SilverlightApplication1.xap',
    parentElement: document.getElementById('silverlightControlHost'),
    id: 'SilverlightObject',
    properties: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        version: '4.0.50401.0'
    },
    events: {
        onError: onSilverlightError,
        onload: null
    }
});
```

I hope that helps you out.